# How to Connect MPLAB ICD2 with Adapter for Pic 18F14K50

Tags: mplab

I want to know the connecting steps for MPLAB ICD 2 with PIC18F14K50 microcontroller Programming adapter and header

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really good [Poster](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/51265e.pdf) from Microchip which explains how to connect the ICD2.
But be aware, the ICD2 is really old and sometimes a little bit tricky. The new ICD4 is easier to use and also much faster.
If you want to work with an header, have a look at this [document](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/header_board_51292m.pdf). It includes also a list of available headers. I am not sure, if there is an header available for the PIC18 for the ICD2.